# Random freezing problem with Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, Lenovo laptop T420

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, freeze

I have dual boot system on my laptop (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). I do not face any freezing problem with Windows 7, it runs smoothly.

Whereas sometime in random interval I face freezing problem with Ubuntu. At this moment mouse key boards does not work. This problem persist even after upgrading BIOS.

I have tried existing solution with no luck. Please let me know what all  other information is required to understand this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First check your laptop specification. Basically there is much trouble with some hardware for you kernel. and also the performance of your integrated graphic.

In case someone else finds this, a kernel upgrade fixed a similar problem.
I had Ubuntu 14.04.2 kernel version 3.16.0-30, and doing a "apt -y upgrade" ended me up at kernel 3.16.0-49, and that solved the problem.

Comment: As of now my kernel version is `3.13.0-71-generic`. I will try to upgrade to kernel `3.16.x` and let you know if I face similar issue.

Comment: Now, I have upgraded kernel version to `3.16.0-55-generic`, still same issue. No improvements.